# Data from field entry are not reflecting in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to add a field in my form but i can't seem to get it to go to phpMyAdmin. Here's the code i used

```
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="location" id="location" value="" autofocus required>
                </div>
            </div>
```

It does not come up in the front end using this code

```
        <p>
            <?php echo $row['location'];?>
        </p>
    </div></div>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? **Data from field entry are not reflecting in phpmyadmin**. Post the entire code. I suppose you're entering the values to DB.

Comment: i tried entering a data in the field but when i check phpMyAdmin, it does not appear there. please check here https://gist.github.com/gcrespiritu1709/93e16de887fead868bbff6d1ac3dfb4c

Comment: `admin/project/create` What's the code inside this endpoint?

Comment: You haven't shown us the code where you try to save the data from this form into the database, or really given us a useful description of the problem - "can't seem to" is pretty much meaningless in terms of giving us any technical detail.  So it's difficult to help you. Please provide a [mre] of the issue. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post.